# I couldn't see Conflict tables in replication monitor SQL Server 2008 R2 in Merge Replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, replication, merge-replication

I work with merge replication in SQL Server 2008 R2. In the replication monitor I can't see conflict table, I must to see conflict tables in "MSmerge_conflicts_info", please help me.

How to see conflict tables in replication monitor? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot see the conflict tables from within Replication Monitor.

However, you can view the Conflict Viewer by right-clicking your Merge Publication in Object Explorer -> View Conflicts.

Alternatively, you can directly query MSmerge_conflicts_info.

For more information, see [View and Resolve Data Conflicts for Merge Publication (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152576.aspx) and [Microsoft Replication Conflict Viewer (Merge Replication)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189029.aspx).